# Why is OpenGL designed in a way that the actual functions have to be loaded manually at runtime?

Tags: opengl

I just had a read through [Loading OpenGL Functions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) and wondered why OpenGL is designed that way, instead of the *easy way*, providing a dynamic library and the according headers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> providing a dynamic library and the according headers?

Then you have a misunderstanding of how a "dynamic library" works.

Let's take Windows as an example. On Windows, if all you had was "a dynamic library and the according headers", you would still be unable to just load that DLL and use it. Even the use of `__declspec(dllimport)` declarations in the header is *insufficient*. You need one more thing: an import library. This is a `.lib` that effectively does the job of loading function pointers for you when you load that DLL.

In short, it's syntactic sugar: nice to have, but not essential. A lot like an OpenGL Loading Library.

On Linux, things are a bit different. SO files are more self contained; they basically store the equivalent of an import library within them. So there, you could in theory get by with "a dynamic library and the according headers".

Even so, it's still sugar; you can dynamically load them and fetch function pointers manually if you wish.

All of that sugar theoretically could be used with OpenGL. But let's think about the ramifications of that.

On Windows, the import library is statically linked to your application. Therefore, it *must* work; if it fails to find the DLL, or that DLL does not provide the functions it ought to, then your program cannot run. At all. That's what most of those "missing DLL" errors are about; some static import library trying to find a DLL that doesn't exist.

So... what if I want to write an application that uses OpenGL 3.3 as a minimum, but is able to use features from OpenGL 4.5 if they are present? I can't link to the OpenGL 4.5 import library, since it'll fail to load on amy 3.3 implementation. So I have to link to the import library for OpenGL 3.3. But then, how do I access the 4.5 functions? That's right: I have to load function pointers if they exist.

So most people are going to have to load some functions *anyway*. It's much cleaner to just load the whole thing. That way, you don't have to have versioned import libraries.

Also, by loading all OpenGL functions dynamically, you don't have to wait for your OS vendor to update their DLL before you can use the next set of OpenGL functions. The main DLL simply provides a connection to the IHV driver DLL (or Open source driver on Linux) that actually implements OpenGL.

Note that Microsoft's OpenGL32.dll still only provides OpenGL **1.1**. So I'd say we've benefited from not waiting on them ;)

Also, we have "the easy way": use an [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: On OS X you can just use a dynamic library and the associated headers.  The functions not available at load time will be NULL.  I believe similar functionality is possible on Linux and Windows, but nobody's gone to the effort of making it work on those platforms.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: You mean, except for [libepoxy](https://github.com/anholt/libepoxy), [several](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_No_Load_C) of [glLoadGen's generators](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_No_Load_CPP), and the defunct GLee. OpenGL Loaders that don't require an explicit initialization step are far from uncommon. Oh, and *when* exactly will OSX be supporting any OpenGL version higher than 4.1? Never, since they're pushing Metal.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Seems like I forgot to mention that with dynamic library I meant the `.dll` *and* `.lib` file ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas: I should clarify: by "similar functionality" I mean that the work is done by the system's loader.  I'm aware of loader libraries that don't require explicit initialization.  And yes, part of the reason why people don't use it is because you still have to wait for your vendor, which if that vendor is Apple, might not make you very happy.  But if you target e.g. 4.1 on OS X, then you needn't bother with any kind of GL loader, and you can still support 3.3.

Comment: There's also the problem of multiple Installable Client Drivers in Windows. Unlike GLX, the extension functions returned by WGL are going to vary depending on which implementation your context is running on (you can get extension addresses in GLX before you even have a context, in fact). There are too many architectural differences to do things the "easy way."